# Converting HTML to DOM for manipulation in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, dom

If I'm scraping some raw HTML from a page, or otherwise making a string of HTML, can I convert that to a DOM/NodeList object? Then can I manipulate objects in that NodeList and save it again as a string?

Something like this

```
request( url, function ( err, response, body ) {
    var bodyDOM = DOM.parse( body ) // assuming body is RAW html

    var images = bodyDOM.getElementByTagName( 'img' )

    for( i = 0; i <= images.length; i++ ) {
        images[i].src = "my-replacement-image.jpg" // does something to the elements int he NodeList

        if ( i == images.length ) {
            console.log( bodyDom ) // HTML with images replaced
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Look into cheerio (https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: @cejast that seems to be a jQuery implementation in Node and I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: @Noah, it is not the jQuery implementation. It just has jQuery-alike API which is comfortable to work with. `cheerio` is a good suggestion. It is much faster and tinier than `jsdom`

Comment: @tenbits Hmm, maybe I will try it because this does seem pretty slow.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the jsdom module.

```
jsdom.env( article.content, function ( error, window ) {

    images = window.document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )

    // ... edit some stuff

    article.content = window.document.body.innerHTML

})
```